# Do I have to set the GoogleMapsApi-script into html?

Tags: javascript, html

First I gotta tell you, I'm a rookie in javascript and web api. 
I know, that the api-script should be placed at the end of the body in the HTML-file. I took the following example of google.
(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=en) I used the partition for the css, html and js that was in the jsfiddle-demonstration in the "Try it yourself"-section.

My question now is: is it possible to integrate the web-api-address-script which is located in the body of the html-file directly into the javascript-file?

```js
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- This is normally placed in the body of the html-file -->
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key.--> 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            async defer></script>
```

Comment: Directly into which JS file?

Comment: The first code is the javascript code.

Comment: If you're talking about the script that gets called in the `<script>` tag at the end of your example, then no. It is provided by Google and we probably don't have access to the code. You can, however, call it from a separate .js file, which you will then have to call from the html. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37606206/313194) shows how to do that.

If you're talking about the js script before the `<script>` tag in your example, the answer is yes. Just throw it in  a .js file and call it from your html.

Comment: Thx for replies.
The reason why I want to do this is, I want to use the Google Api for a CRM system to autocomplete address data. 
My aim was not to set this 
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            async defer></script> 
into the body of the html-file of our company-website. I wanted to use only one javascript instead to do the whole work - without any call from an html-file.

I hoped that there could be a solution with maybe jQuery.